# Fetch data from mysql using EBean

Tags: java, mysql, ebean

I am trying to make a simple program to fetch data from a table. 
I am following http://www.avaje.org/ebean/getstarted_props.html#iud but am unable to get data. I have created new **Entity Class from Database** from Netbeans (which creates classes from relations). Here is what I am using:

**ebean.properties**

```
ebean.ddl.generate=true  
ebean.ddl.run=true    
ebean.debug.sql=true  
ebean.debug.lazyload=false
ebean.logging=all  
ebean.logging.logfilesharing=all  
ebean.logging.directory=D:\\logs  
ebean.logging.iud=sql  
ebean.logging.query=sql  
ebean.logging.sqlquery=sql    
ebean.logging.txnCommit=none  
datasource.default=h2    
datasource.h2.username=sa  
datasource.h2.password=  
datasource.h2.databaseUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:tests;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1  
datasource.h2.databaseDriver=org.h2.Driver  
datasource.h2.minConnections=1  
datasource.h2.maxConnections=25  
datasource.h2.heartbeatsql=select 1  
datasource.h2.isolationlevel=read_committed    
datasource.mysql.username=root  
datasource.mysql.password=kalsym@123  
datasource.mysql.databaseUrl=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/wsp  
datasource.mysql.databaseDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
datasource.mysql.minConnections=1  
datasource.mysql.maxConnections=25   
datasource.mysql.isolationlevel=read_committed
```

**Table Data**

```
Insert into routing_algo_type (name, description) values ('LCR', 'Least Cost Routing');
```

**Code to fetch data**

```
RoutingAlgoType routingObj = new RoutingAlgoType();
routingObj.setName("LCR");
RoutingAlgoType routingObj2  = Ebean.find(RoutingAlgoType.class, routingObj);
System.out.println("Got "+routingObj2.getDescription());
```

Now find returns null, which means it cant find the data?

I used following code to test connection

```
String sql = "select count(*) as count from dual";
SqlRow row = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql).findUnique();
Integer i = row.getInteger("count");
System.out.println("Got " + i + "  - DataSource good.");
```

Result from above code is

**Got 1  - DataSource good.**

Is there any way to check the connection?